# C - Allocating memory to a pointer to a member in a Struct

Tags: c, pointers, dynamic-memory-allocation

I've already seen a lot of other questions, however I still can't seem to figure out how to initialize a pointer to a struct member that is also a pointer.  Given my pointer to my struct (which contains a member that is a pointer) I want to initialize a pointer to that member pointer.

For example when adding a node to a linked list the parameter given in the examples which I have learned are addNode(**head, etc).  I would like to know whether or not I need to allocate memory to this pointer and how to initialize it if I'm doing it wrong in the code below.

```
int row, col;
double val;
char nwln;

sp_tuples_node ** tuplepointer/* = malloc(sizeof(sp_tuples_node *));*/

FILE * inFile = fopen(input_file, "r");
sp_tuples * new_tuples = malloc(sizeof(sp_tuples));
tuplepointer = new_tuples->tuples_head;
fscanf(inFile, "%d %d%c", &row, &col, &nwln);

  //while not eof
  fscanf(inFile, "%d %d %d%c", &row, &col, &val, &nwln);
  addNode(tuplepointer, row, col, val);
  return new_tuples;
```

The line in question is separated by new lines the rest of the non completed code is there for context of calling the function and its functionality should be disregarded.

Thank you for any feedback regarding how to assign pointers to members that are pointers.

Comment: What is `sp_tuples_node`? That sounds like Hungarian Notation for a `typedef` pointer-to-struct. I don't think it's a good idea to mix typedefs and multiple pointers in the same declaration (`sp_tuples_node** tuplepointer`) because it's unclear how much pointer-indirection is going on.

Comment: I'm seeing a lot of immediate use of invalid memory (`malloc` doesn't zero memory after allocation whereas, `calloc` does), for example `tuplepointer = new_tuples->tuples_head` right after `new_tuples = malloc(sizeof(sp_tuples))` - you shouldn't do that and a smart compiler will give you a warning.

Comment: I tried looking for a tag regarding a homework style format however I could not find one this is NOT the answer to the hw (just to clarify I'm not trying to get answers).  I cannot change the dumb notation (I agree makes it really hard to read).  Thank you for pointing out my error however I will add that to my fixes for this.  For the pointer to the member in the Struct should I allocate memory for the entire separate type `(ex: tuplepointer = calloc(sizeof(tuple_node_struct)`

Comment: or should I just initialize a pointer like `(tuple_node_struct ** tuplepointer;)` `tuplepointer = new_tuples->tuples_head`

Comment: I can't help further without knowing your `struct` definitions.Please post your **full** code, including any header files, especially any `typedef` and `struct` statements.

Comment: Note that [`while (!feof(file))` is always wrong](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5431941/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whenever you declare a type *pointer-to-pointer-to* `type` you require *two* allocations before you can make use of any of the *pointer-to* `type` referenced through the *pointer-to-pointer-to* `type` (or at minimum one allocation of pointers and then an assignment of an existing object to each of the allocated pointers).

Take for example your declaration of:

```
sp_tuples_node **tuplepointer;
```

(presuming `std_tuples_node` is not some typedeffed pointer)

What you need to do is:

- first allocate some number of **pointers**. Why? You have a *pointer-to-pointer*. That is a single-pointer holding the address of a *pointer-to* `type`. If you want reference `50` of the type object referred to, you must allocate `50` pointers so that `tuplepointer` points to a block of memory that contains `50` pointers to type `sp_tuples_node`.

For example:

```
tuplepointer = malloc (50 * sizeof *tuplepointer);    /* allocate 50 pointers */
if (!tuplepointer) {                                  /* validate allocation */
    perror ("malloc-tuplepointer");
    exit (EXIT_FAILURE);
}
```

- second, you can allocate storage for each `sp_tuples_node` and assign the starting address for each block allocated to one of the `50` pointers in the block of memory you have allocated and assigned to `tuplepointer` above.

For example:

```
for (size_t i = 0; i < 50; i++) {
    tuplepointer[i] = malloc (sizeof *tuplepointer[i]);
    if (!tuplepointer[i]) {
        perror ("malloc-tuplepointer[i]");
        exit (EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
}
```

(**note:** if you always use the *dereferenced pointer* to set the *typesize* for the type you are allocating -- you will never get your *typesize* wrong)

Now you have allocated storage for `50` pointers and assigned the starting address to `tuplepointer`. You have also allocates storage for `50 - sp_tuples_node` and you have assigned the starting address for each to one of the `50` pointers in the block assigned to `tuplepointer`. You can reference each `sp_tuples_node` using *array-index* notation as `tuplepointer[i]`.

If `sp_tuples_node` contains yet another pointer to some type as a member of the struct you can now allocate a block of storage and assign the starting address to that pointer.  Say you have `char *str;` as a member of `sp_tuples_node`. You can then allocate:

```
size_t len = strlen(somestring);
tuplepointer[i]->str = malloc (len + 1);   /* allocate storage for str, assign to ptr */
/* validate allocation ... */
memcpy (typlepointer[i]->str, somestring, len + 1);
```

And so on and so forth... You can do this as many times as needed. The only thing you need to keep straight is whether you are allocating pointers, or allocating storage for an object. Obviously with a *pointer-to-pointer-to* `type` you are allocating pointers, when you derefernce once and need to allocate for *pointer-to* `type` you are allocating storage for an object.

**How do you keep it straight?**

Think of it this way. When you derefernce the type you are allocating for -- what do you have?

- with a *pointer-to-pointer-to* `type`, when dereferenced you have *pointer-to* `type` (you are allocating pointers)
- with a *pointer-to* `type`, when dereferenced you have `type` (you are allocating for an object)

Lastly, you mention *linked-list* in your question and you mention `addNode(**head, etc)`. That is different. You likely have in that case in the caller (say `main()`)

```
node *head;
```

and you are then calling:

```
addNode (&head, etc);
```

There the parameter type is *pointer-to-pointer-to* `head` because you are passing the *address of* the original pointer back in `main()`. `head` itself already has a valid address, so you do not allocate for `head` itself.

You pass `&head` so the function `addNode` receives the address of the original pointer instead of a *copy-of* the pointer. That way if you need to allocate storage for the node referenced through `head` you can allocate `*head = malloc (sizeof **head);` and upon function return `head` will point to the new block of memory allocated in `addNode()` without having to return and assign the starting address for the newly allocated block of memory.

Let me know if that helps clear it up. If not, I'm happy to try again.

Comment: Thank you very much for your detailed response, with the considerations you provided my code complied (although I may have to change the code entirely depending on if my functionality is correct).  It is as you said in your last section I am trying to implement a program that interacts with some data and stores it as a linked list, I am attempting to implement my own add, rm, and find functions in order to manipulate the data easier.  Not sure if it will work out this way but your explanations explained the topic to me in a very thorough way, even if I have to change it I learned a lot!

Comment: Glad it helped. Good luck with your project. You may find [Singly Linked List (node only, no wrapper)](https://pastebin.com/5MPLU4wB) helpful for a plain linked-list example. Much greater insert efficiency can be obtained by keeping track of both the `head` and `tail` nodes eliminating the need to iterate to find the next point of insertion. You may find [Singly Linked List of Integers (example)](https://pastebin.com/R2AewR3A) instructive there `:)`